# What is the best way to update a custom field on a standard object based on an activity?

Tags: trigger, workflow, field-update

I have a custom field on the Campaign Member object that is called Call_Dispositon__c.  I would like this field to be updated to match what is entered on the Call_Disposition__c field on an Activity. This activity is being created through a custom button, and capturing the Campaign Member ID.  So, I know that I ultimately want this  to happen:

IF(CampaignMemberID==Task.CampaignMemberID, CampaignMember_Call_Disposition__c=Task_Call_Disposition__c)

I am not able to add a lookup field to link the campaign member and task and was not able to create a workflow that would update the field either.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not able to do it using workflow when the Task is inserted, then you'd want to create an AfterInsert trigger on Task. Before you do, you might want to try the new process builder to see if you can do it using that method.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears this cannot be done through a workflow or process builder because the fields are both picklist fields.

Comment: Ahh, workflow wouldn't allow you to use Pickval I take it. That leaves you with a trigger as your only option then.